# uniform convergence of sequence of functions $f_n(x)=x e^{-nx^2} , x\in{\mathbb{R}}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

For $n\ge1$, let $f_n(x)=x e^{-nx^2} , x\in{\mathbb{R}}$.

Then the sequence {$f_n$} is

1.uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$

2.uniformly convergent only on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

3.bounded and not uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$

4.sequence of unbounded functions.

I know that it converges pointwise to 0 for all $x\in{\mathbb{R}}$.

To prove uniform convergence using definition co nsider $\vert{f_n(x)-f(x)}\vert =\vert{x e^{-nx^2}}-0\vert \le \vert{x}\vert $  since $\vert{e^{-nx^2}}\vert\le1$ .But to prove uniform convergence we should find value for N independent of x so how to proceed?

$\vert{f_n(x)}\vert =\vert{x e^{-nx^2}}\vert \le \vert{x}\vert $  hence this is sequence of bounded functions.

Comment: The definition of uniform convergence contains $\sup_x |f_n(x)|$: you need to compute it for all $n$ (or at least have an upper bound for it), otherwise the exercize cannot be solved.

Comment: Hint (already given, with explanations, to your avatar @shwetha): For every $x$ and every $n\geqslant1$, $|f_n(x)|\leqslant1/\sqrt{n}$. Advice: Stop reposting the same question to circumvent the rules of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f'_n(x)=e^{-nx^2}(1-2nx^2)$, hence the odd function $f_n(x)=xe^{-nx^2}$ has a global maximum point at $x_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$. Therefore
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\vert{f_n(x)}\vert=f_n(x_n)=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{\sqrt{2n}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x}{(e^nx^2)}= 0,$$ since for any $x \in  \mathbb R, e^nx^2 $ grows faster than $x.$